# how to make protocol to conform another protocol in Swift?

Tags: swift, protocols

I make a extension for Array where Elements are Object, so I can compare them by their address.

```
public extension Array where Element: AnyObject {
    func hasExactSameItem(_ searchingItem: Element) -> Bool {
        guard let _ = indexOfExactSameItem(searchingItem) else { return false }
        return true
    }
    func indexOfExactSameItem(_ searchingItem: Element) -> Int? {
        for (index, item) in self.enumerated() {
            if searchingItem === item {
                return index
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

There is another protocol conforming AnyObject protocol

```
public protocol IMServerListener: AnyObject {
    
}
```

I have a array containing IMServerListener

```
private var listeners = [IMServerListener]()
```

When I start adding listener to that array, the compiler complaining that '[IMServerListener]' requires that 'IMServerListener' conform to 'AnyObject'

```
func addListener(_ listener: IMServerListener) {
     listeners.hasExactSameItem(listener)
 }
```

I thought the IMServerListener is conforming the AnyObject protocol, so why did it happened?

Comment: This is essentially another version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself). Protocols just don't conform to other protocols. Use a constrained generic type instead. `<T: IMServerListener>` and `listener: T`.

Comment: Not related to your question but in your first method why not simply return `indexOfExactSameItem(searchingItem) != nil` ? The same in your second method  you can simply return `firstIndex { $0 === searchingItem }`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to construct a similar example in a playground:

```
import UIKit

protocol Foo: AnyObject {
    func foo()
}

protocol Bar: Foo {}

class A: Bar {
    func foo() {}
}

var bars = [Bar]()
bars.append(A())
bars.append(A())

bars[0] === bars[1] // equals operator used from AnyObject
```

Observations:
(1) Protocols can inherit from each other. If I leave out the implementation of `foo()` in class `A` it leads to a compiler error.
(2) Class `A` does inherit from `AnyObject` through `Bar` and `Foo` otherwise I could not use the equals operator.

To your question:
`compiler complaining that '[compiler complaining that '[IMServerListener]' requires that 'IMServerListener' conform to 'AnyObject']' requires that 'IMServerListener' conform to 'AnyObject'` sounds like there might be something wrong with the implementation of `IMServerListener` itself.

I am happy to extend my answer if you can show us this implementation / more code in general.

Cheers,
Dominic